# MSSQL how to add dict table

Tags: sql-server

I have a few tables in the MSSQL database that added like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[nazwa.tabeli1](
      [id] [varchar](7) NULL,
      [name] [varchar](16) NULL,
      [surname] [varchar](16) NULL,
      [Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
      [stat] [varchar](3) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

But when I want to add dictionary table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dict].[produkt](
    [ID] [nvarchar](7) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [Height] [nvarchar](4) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I getting:

Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The specified schema name "dict" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

How can I add such a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema does not exist, so try

```
CREATE SCHEMA dict
GO

CREATE TABLE [dict].[produkt](
    [ID] [nvarchar](7) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [Height] [nvarchar](4) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

`dbo` is the default schema that exists always but `dict` not.

http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2012/09/16/setup-sql-server-schema/

However, do you really want to use a separate schema `dict` just for this table?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.

Comment: @BartekK: try again without semicolon and with `GO`.